# How do I get ng-show to work in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I want an image to be displayed (over the top of another image) upon hovering over it's container. I am trying to get this to work with angular and ng-show however I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. The image with the ng-show attribute is never displayed.

```
<header class="header">
    <a routerLink="/">
        <div class="header__link" ng-controller="testCtrl"
             ng-init="show = false"
             ng-mouseenter="show = true"
             ng-mouseleave="show = false">
            <img class="header__link--logo" src="assets/img/logo2.jpeg">
            <img class="header__link--logo--hover" src="assets/img/logo2hover.jpeg"
                 ng-show="show">
            <h1 class="header__link--title">
                INMOCO
            </h1>
        </div>
    </a>
    <nav>

    </nav>
</header>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

console.log("app");

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.show = false;
});
```

Please help me understand why the angular specific code is not working or an easier way to do this. Thank you!

Comment: looking at your code you aren't using angular 8 but rather angularjs.

Comment: Updated question to reflect proper version of angular

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the `ng-app` directive:

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

### The DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.show = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
  <header class="header">
  <a routerLink="/">
     <div class="header__link" ng-controller="testCtrl"
             ng-init="show = false"
             ng-mouseenter="show = true"
             ng-mouseleave="show = false">
            <img class="header__link--logo" src="assets/img/logo2.jpeg">
            <img class="header__link--logo--hover" src="assets/img/logo2hover.jpeg"
                 ng-show="show">
            <h1 class="header__link--title">
                INMOCO
            </h1>
      </div>
    <nav>

    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The images need to be styled with `position: absolute` or the "hover" image will not render on top of the "base" image. You can also control showing and hiding of the image entirely in CSS, using angular to do this is a bit overkill.

```css
.image {
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}

.hover-image {
    display: none;
}

.image-container:hover .hover-image {
    display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="image base-image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/slightly-frowning-face.png">
    <img class="image hover-image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/slightly-smiling-face.png">
</div>
```